# Women and arba minim on first day

Tags: halacha, women, transactions, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

On the first day there is a din of "lechem" ("to you") that the arba minim must belong to you. Many women will take the arba minim of their father or husband (or brother perhaps) in order to fulfill the mitzvah of arba minim.

Must they be careful to be koneh it in a way that it will be considered theirs (kol dinei "lechem")?

I realize this is rather simple and the dinim of lechem also apply to women. However a very big Rav today said he was in doubt about this since l'maseh women are not obligated from the mitzvah and seem to be fulfilling it as some what of a "minhag".

I would particularly appreciate any discussion or sources on this inyun of lechem in regards to women.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Birkey Yakov says a husband should be מקנה his 4 minim to his wife.

http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=68485